# Google AppEngine dev_appserver raises ImportError despite package being installed in virtualenv and available in Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm working on a Google AppEngine project that uses the legacy Python 2.7 runtime - my team is migrating away from this, however we're still using it for the time being. Local development has worked fine for me for the last ~6 months, and no one else on my team is affected by the following issue.

I'm getting an `ImportError` when starting `dev_appserver.py`, as well as during handling of any requests:

```
09:36:59 dev_server.1    | ERROR    2021-05-13 13:36:59,470 wsgi.py:269] 
09:36:59 dev_server.1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |     handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |     handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |     obj = __import__(path[0])
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/Users/me/Source/myproject/main.py", line 5, in <module>
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |     import webapp2
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 25, in <module>
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |     import webob
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/private/var/folders/qs/2qn9hbhn3k77wbhgsg77w6tm0000gn/T/pip-target-etkWjd/lib/python/webob/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |   File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1168, in load_module
09:36:59 dev_server.1    |     raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
09:36:59 dev_server.1    | ImportError: No module named webob.datetime_utils
```

As you can see, the error happens on importing `webapp2`, which calls `import webob`. `webob` is installed both in my virtualenv:

```
(myenv) me@pegasus site % pip list | grep WebOb
WebOb                         1.8.7
```

As well as specified in `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
...
- name: webob
  version: "1.2.3"
...
```

I've ensured that my virtualenv is active at the time I start `dev_appserver.py`.

The curious thing to me is this line of the traceback:

```
09:36:59 dev_server.1  |  File "/private/var/folders/qs/2qn9hbhn3k77wbhgsg77w6tm0000gn/T/pip-target-etkWjd/lib/python/webob/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
```

I have no idea why code in `/private/var/folders` is being executed - shouldn't it be calling the code in my virtualenv or the code provided with the Google Cloud SDK?

It appears to be in the SDK - the caller is `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py`, however I can find no reason as to why the resolved path for `webob` is in `/private/var/folders` as opposed to my virtualenv or, more sensibly, the `webob-1.2.3` package also located in `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/`!

In fact, in ~6 years of developing Python full time, I've never seen such a filepath in a traceback - I'd always expect executed code to be in either my own files or `site-packages` of the associated virtualenv.

Additionally, the file in the traceback doesn't exist (or isn't visible to me, at least): attempting to `ls` the `/private/var/folders/qs/2qn9hbhn3k77wbhgsg77w6tm0000gn/T/pip-target-etkWjd/` directory results in `No such file or directory`.

**What I've tried:**

1. Completely removed & reinstalled both my virtualenv and Google Cloud SDK.
2. Removed the `pip` installed instance of `webob`.
3. Reinstalled `webob` with the same version that comes with the SDK (1.2.3).
4. Installed a new instance of python2.7 with `pyenv` and used it to remove & re-create my virtualenv.
5. Removed all extraneous entries from my `PATH` to see if some entry was causing the import system to resolve `webob` in an unexpected way.

None of this has worked. Ultimately, I'm still not sure how an import can ever fail if the package is installed in the active virtualenv - I'd expect that the `webapp2` module in the Google Cloud SDK would resolve the import via the virtualenv, but I'm definitely not an expert on the import system.

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling WebOb from your virtual environment.  GAE first gen wants to use its own internal WebOb so the presence of WebOb in your virtual environment might be confusing things.

Comment: @gaefan Thanks for taking a look! I had the same thought but unfortunately that doesn't help. For good measure, I just tried again with my new virtualenv but the result is the same.

I've verified the internal WebOb is present in the SDK folders, so I'm not sure why it can't be found by `sandbox.py` during the import process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the following code to `/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py` before the attempted import of `webob`:

```
import imp
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('webob')
print '--------------------------'
print fp
print pathname
print description
print '--------------------------'
```

Which printed out:

```
14:03:13 dev_server.1    |--------------------------
14:03:13 dev_server.1    | None
14:03:13 dev_server.1    | /Users/me/Source/myproject/lib/webob
14:03:13 dev_server.1    | ('', '', 5)
14:03:13 dev_server.1    | --------------------------
```

This `webob` directory in `lib` was unexpected - it's included with the python2 runtime on GAE as well as in the SDK, and thus doesn't need to be vendored in `lib`. It was also empty, and so I hadn't noticed it because `git` didn't report any new untracked files.

I'm not quite sure of the mechanism, but this was causing the import issue - as soon as I removed the empty directory, the issue was resolved.